# strtok for UTF-8 documents in Linux

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, strtok

I am using strtok for tokenizing UTF-8 texts. It's working correctly in Ubuntu 32-bit but in Ubuntu 64-bit it can't tokenize some words, for example "bölen". strtok thinks there are two words: "b" and "�len". My code sample is below.

I want to know how can I solve that issue in 64-bit Linux, and why is it working in 32-bit Linux correctly?

```
char* str = const_cast<char*>(content.c_str());
char * tokenizedWord;
tokenizedWord = strtok(str, " !'^+%&/\()=?_-*.,;:<>|´`~¨}][{#");
```

EDIT1
Both OS' locales are same:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

EDIT2 I am using below function to initialize the content:

```
content = fileImport(path+ "/" + fileName);


string fileImport(string filePath) {
string line, content;
ifstream myfile(filePath.c_str());
if (myfile.is_open()) {
    while (myfile.good()) {
        getline(myfile, line);
        content.append(line);
    }
    myfile.close();
} else
    fprintf(stderr, "\nFile is cant read\n");
return content;
```

}

Comment: Instead of `const_cast<char*>(content.c_str());`, it might be better if you use `&content[0]` (assuming `std::basic_string`).

Comment: Is the locale the same for both systems? It's probably unrelated to the bit-ness

Comment: What's the byte-wise content of `content`?

Comment: @KerrekSB If he's telling the truth, and it is UTF-8, then it should be `0x62, 0xC3, 0xB6, 0x6C, 0x65, 0x6E`.  And he seems to be getting a `0xFD` in his output.  I can't figure out where that's coming from either.  Maybe something about how `content` is sourced is messing up.  I agree that his first step should be to do a hex dump of the initial string.

Comment: Just for the record, you shouldn't be using `strtok`.  It depends on static state, which means that it can't be used in a multithreaded environment, and is very dangerous in a single threaded environment.

Comment: @MarkGarcia Only if undefined behavior bothers him.  Using `&content[0]` would result in defined behavior; officially only since C++11, but practically, C++11 just standardized existing behavior, so there should be no problem.  (In practice, in most implementations, `content.c_str()` and `&content[0]` will return the same address, and he should get away with it.  But it is definitely not guaranteed.)

Comment: @JamesKanze So is there any alternative for strtok?

Comment: @Yavuz On `std::string`, all of the functions in `<algorithm>` work, and `std::string` has a number of special member functions as well.  In this case, for example, you might use `std::string tokenizedWord( content.begin(), std::find_first_of( content.begin(), content.end(), delimiters.begin(), delimiters.end() );`; you might also want to save the results of `std::find_first_of` for later use.

Comment: @Yavuz Well, you're using the results of `std::getline` without checking that the function succeeded, which is clearly an error (but probably not the source of your problem).  You're loop should be `while ( std::getline( myfile, line ) ) content.append( line );`.  And you're not inserting separators between the lines, which is probably not what you want either.  (But again, almost certainly not the reason behind the problem you describe.)

Comment: Can you insert code to give a hex dump of `content` just before the problem point?  (Or for that matter, can you look at it in a debugger.)  That would make it clear whether the problem is in the input routine or in `strtok`.  (I somehow doubt that it is in `strtok`.  `strtok` has been around for years, and is locale independent, so shouldn't have undergone any changes.

Comment: ``strtok`` is only designed to operate on ASCII strings. It's not unicode aware at all, so in some circumstances it will split words inside utf-8 multibyte characters & trying to split on a multibyte character will not work at all. However, for this particular example it ought to be fine & my own test code works so I don't know what the OP is doing wrong!

Comment: @MarkGarcia, if you say &content[0] the taken address isn't guaranteed to be be base-address of a zero-terminated string. I often thought myself that it would have been best if c_str() would specified to return a non-const char *.

Answer (score -1):

I used Boost Tokenizer. It's working correctly. You can find information from [that](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/tokenizer/tokenizer.htm) link.